# preg_replace and large text file parsing

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-replace

I'm having a strange issue with `preg_replace`.  It seems to behave normally with single strings, but when I bring a large text file (~1.5MB) it seems to just do nothing.

I'm trying to parse a large text file of key-values which has this kind of structure:

```
"KeyValues"
{
    "Key1" "Value1"
    // a comment
    "ComplexKey" 
    {
        "ComplexKey1" "ComplexValue1" // another comment
        "ComplexKey2" "ComplexValue2"
        "FurtherComplexity1" 
        {
            "ComplexKey3" "ComplexValue3"
            "ComplexKey4" "ComplexValue4"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to remove the comments from the text-file before I do any parsing.  `preg_replace` seemed like a safe bet.  Here's the code for just removing the comments:

```
<?php

$filecontent = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$filecontent = preg_replace('!//.*!s', '', $filecontent);

echo $filecontent;

?>
```

Now I expect it to output the example above without the comments, but it just returns the exact same string it starts out with.  Where it gets weird though is it I take a single line out from the text file, for example this one:

```
        "ComplexKey1" "ComplexValue1" // another comment
```

I can run the `preg_replace` call on that string and it'll return the string without the comment.  I thought maybe it was because there was some new-line characters not matching the regular expression, so I added the 's' modifier to the expression; however, this didn't seem to fix the problem.  For whatever reason, my `preg_replace` call just won't do anything (or my regular expression is off).

An obvious solution would be just to ignore comments in the parsing, but I'm thinking there must be something I'm missing here as to why this isn't working.  I'd really like to fix this without changing the parser, if at all possible.  Any ideas?

Comment: You are using the *s (PCRE_DOTALL)* modifier, you should understand what it does firsthand. Not just trying and wondering, but also understanding. http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Also you might want to convert that file-format into something supported, like JSON or YAML maybe. Libraries to parse these exist already (JSON has no comments however).

Answer (score 3):

```
$filecontent = preg_replace('!//.*$!m', '', $filecontent);
```

`m` modifier changes the processing of the input text to line by line

> By default, PCRE treats the subject string as consisting of a single "line" of characters (even if it actually contains several newlines). The "start of line" metacharacter (^) matches only at the start of the string, while the "end of line" metacharacter ($) matches only at the end of the string, or before a terminating newline (unless D modifier is set). This is the same as Perl. When this modifier is set, the "start of line" and "end of line" constructs match immediately following or immediately before any newline in the subject string, respectively, as well as at the very start and end. This is equivalent to Perl's /m modifier. If there are no "\n" characters in a subject string, or no occurrences of ^ or $ in a pattern, setting this modifier has no effect.

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: And also `.` does not match the newline character, which it did with *s (PCRE_DOTALL)*.

Comment: I don't understand why -- but my problem was fixed by copying all of the text from the text file into a new one, and running the code on the new text file... runs just fine now (without even implementing the change here).

Comment: @canadiancaper: your current code means: "remove everything from the first `//` entry to the end of the file"

Comment: @hakra: `$` there changes nothing. Both regexes (original and to what you've changes) work the same

Comment: `$` marks end of line and is sort of cosmetic, right (you do not explicitly need it as with *m* modifier *only*, `.` would not match end-of-line anyway). however, before with *s* modifier `.` did actually match end of line, too. So that after the first `//.*` everything would have been replaced.

Comment: @canadiancaper You could compare the [tag:character-encoding] of the files? PHP may be triggered in using the wrong decoding.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Can you use

```
json_decode($mydata,true)
```

to turn your whole text file into a nice multi level php array.